# Method to add a trace in smali

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, trace, smali

I did a smali class with only one method so far to add a `logcat` trace to any method. I can compile and launch the app but the method prints nothing.

I have one local parameter which is a simple `tag` for `logcat` this local paramater is `v0`, I get it from the method I want to add a trace in. And a parameter `p0`. I believe there is something wrong but the dalvik debugger prints nothing wrong therefore I have no clue where my mistake is.

Below is my code.

```
.class public Landroid/MyCustomClass;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "MyCustomClass.java"

.method public static add_trace(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .locals 1

    .prologue   
    const-string v0, "myTag" 

    .line 10
    invoke-static {v0, p0}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    .line 13
        return-void
.end method
```

Here is an example of how I invoke the method:

```
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 157
    const-string v0, "settings.properties"

    invoke-direct {p0, v0}, Lse/smartrefill/AbstractApplication;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 158
    # has been edited 
    const-string v0, "<init>()V" 
    invoke-static {v0}, Landroid/MyCustomClass;->add_trace(Ljava/lang/String;)V 
    return-void
.end method
```

To go even further I would like to know if there is any way to print out the value of the returned register of a method as well.

I am aware that every type of variable in Java inherit from Object and that Object has a method `toString()` so theoriticly it should be possible to customise my method `add_trace()` to get the value of the returned register during the runtime. Could someone help me with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the first part of my problem by modifiying my method as follow:

```
.method public static add_trace(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .locals 1
    .param p0, "my_message" # Ljava/lang/String;

    .prologue   
    const-string v0, "my_tag" 

    .line 10
    invoke-static {v0, p0}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    .line 13
        return-void
.end method
```

Here is my code to print the returned register as well I didn't test it yet though:

```
.method public static add_trace(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    .locals 3
    .param p0, "my_message"     # Ljava/lang/String;
    .param p1, "returned_register"  # Ljava/lang/Object;

    .prologue   
    .line 25
    const-string v0, "my_tag" 

    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-direct {v1, p0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    const-string v2, ":"

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Ljava/lang/Object;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-static {v0, v1}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    .line 48
    return-void
.end method
```